# Trigger MeshLab reload by script

Tags: triggers, cad, meshlab

Is it possible to reload a 3d object in MeshLab by an external script?
I know reloading an object can be achieved by pressing the refresh button (see image below). However, I would like to know if this behaviour can be triggered externally.
[image: screenshot]

The reason I would like to be able to do this is because I want to use MeshLab as a visual tool to see the objects I've created with [ImplicitCad](http://www.implicitcad.org/docs/tutorial). Object are created by writing code, which can be executed to produce an .stl file. MeshLab can read the file to show me the object I made. 
When I save my code I would like to run a script that:

1. creates an .stl file from my code (This can be done using [extopenscad](https://github.com/colah/ImplicitCAD#try-implicitcad))
2. reloads the object loaded in MeshLab (I don't know how to do this, or if it is even possible)

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me!

Comment: did you find an answer to this?

Comment: @sdfsdf No, unfortunately not.